# How to create a file object with a path in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I want to know if it is possible to create a `File` object (name, size, data, ...) in NodeJS with the path of an existing file? I know that it is possible client side but I see nothing for NodeJS.

In others words, I want the same function as this that works in NodeJS :

```
function srcToFile(src, fileName, mimeType){
    return (fetch(src)
        .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
        .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], fileName, {type:mimeType});})
    );
}

srcToFile('/images/logo.png', 'logo.png', 'image/png')
.then(function(file){
    console.log(file);
});
```

And output would be like:

```
File {name: "logo.png", lastModified: 1491465000541, lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 06 2017 09:50:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 49029, type:"image/png"…}
```

Comment: You're looking for [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback), though if you want the data inside the file you'll need to merge it with [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched for File Systems examples and other possibilities and found nothing.

So I decide to create my own File object with JSON.

```
  var imagePath = path.join('/images/logo.png', 'logo.png');
    
  if (fs.statSync(imagePath)) {
     var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
     var bufferImage = new Buffer(bitmap);
    
     Magic = mmm.Magic;
     var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
     magic.detectFile(imagePath, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          datas = [{"buffer": bufferImage, "mimetype": result, "originalname": path.basename(imagePath)}];
          var JsonDatas= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(datas));
          log.notice(JsonDatas);
     });
 }
```

The output :

```
{ 
  buffer:
  { 
    type: 'Buffer',
    data:
    [ 
      255,
      216,
      255
      ... 24908 more items,
      [length]: 25008 
    ] 
  },
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  originalname: 'logo.png' 
}
```

I think is probably not the best solution, but it give me what I want. If you have a better solution, you are welcome to suggest it.

Comment: mmmagic appears to be very out of date now. I got errors when trying to use mmmagic (in 2023), see [mmmagic issues #168](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic/issues/168). There's a few others with similar problems. I would suggest trying [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) or [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) instead.

Comment: I don't understand why you do `var JsonDatas= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(datas));`. `datas` is already a javascript object, you then convert it to text and back to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

For those that are looking for a solution to this problem, I created an npm package to make it easier to retrieve files using Node's file system and convert them to JS File objects:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-file-object-from-local-path

This solves the lack of interoperability between Node's fs file system (which the browser doesn't have access to), and the browser's File object type, which Node cannot create.

3 steps are required:

1. Get the file data in the Node instance and construct a LocalFileData object from it
2. Send the created LocalFileData object to the client
3. Convert the LocalFileData object to a File object in the browser.

```
// Within node.js
const fileData = new LocalFileData('path/to/file.txt')

// Within browser code
const file = constructFileFromLocalFileData(fileData)
```

Comment: This is a truly awesome final piece of a puzzle for being able to expose files directly in your electron web app without having to use the file picker.

Answer (score 0):

My use case for this was in my Electron app. The files here are based on the [Electron Quick Start](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start).

I want to have a `File` object similar to what I would get after selecting a file via `<input type="file" />` or via the [Drop event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drop_event), but I want to use the extra power of electron and it's Node direct file access without needing to request file access permissions as with the File System Access API.

Thanks to [@abr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66263096/327074) I have a complete solution now:

**`main.js`**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const { LocalFileData } = require('get-file-object-from-local-path')

let win

const createWindow = () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    })

    ipcMain.handle('get-file', async (event, filePath) => {
        try {
            const data = new LocalFileData(filePath)
            return [data]
        } catch (e) {
            return [null, e]
        }
    })
    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
})
```

**`preload.js`**:

```js
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron')
const { constructFileFromLocalFileData } = require('get-file-object-from-local-path')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    getFile: async (filePath) => {
        const [data, error] = await ipcRenderer.invoke('get-file', filePath)
        if (!data) {
            return [data, error]
        }
        return [constructFileFromLocalFileData(data), error]
    },
})
```

**`renderer.js`**:

```js
const filePath = '/path/to/my/file.jpg'
const [file] = await window.electronAPI.getFile(filePath)
console.log(file)
```

You could arguably do the `constructFileFromLocalFileData` in `renderer.js` to keep any logic out of `preload.js`.

However it seems more sensible that the `renderer.js` can treat `getFile` as something similar to a file picker and so get a standard `File` object back. Since preload runs in the renderer environment but with also access to Node modules it seems like a sensible place to do it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use arrayBuffer (thats what i did to make a downloadable pdf) or createReadStream / createWriteStream under fs(FileSystem objects)