# In electron, how to upload a file from it's full filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, electron, axios

In my electron app I have a button that says "upload contract".

When clicked it looks from the stored contract's filename ie. `/home/users/filename.docx` and gets it (no need for a dialog window).

Now, I have problems uploading this file as a multipart form data while using axios.

I've read about [this issue, asking for file upload on axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/2) which led to [this pull request for file upload on browser](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/pull/22) and [this pull for uploading in node.js](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/pull/296).

I've read through the issues and comments applying bit by bit but seems to have troubles getting the real file uploading right using axios.

Here is what I have been doing.

**Upload as browser**

```js
export function generateContract(fileUrl, customer) {
    const data = new FormData()
    const file = fs.createReadStream(fileUrl)

    data.append('names', customer.names)
    data.append('email', customer.email)
    data.append('contract', file)

    return data
}

//- In between generateContract & uploadFile function some function
//- gets the generatedContract data & push it to uploadFile for axios uploading.

//- In API file.

export function uploadFile(formData) {
    return checkConnetion()
        .then(() => {
            return axios.post(emailUrl, formData)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return axios.post(emailUrlOffline, formData)
        })
}
```

In generatedContract I'm using `FormData` that (I assume) is a global function in browsers to create a form instance for uploading files.

I'm also using `fs.createReadStream` cause without it my file upload looks like an object with three strings (the fileUrl gets to be a normal string).

However, uploading like this and `console.log`ing my request body from my local server I get a hopeless

```
{ names: 'Mwajuma Salmin',
  email: 'sammwaj@yahoo.com',
  contract: '[object Object]' }
```

The contract file is `[object Object]'.

**Uploading as node.js**

Everything is the same, except I'm using npm's [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data).

Output is.

```
{ '[object FormData]': '' }
```

Where am I messing up?

I tried uploading with postman and manually selected the file to upload as form-data and that other data (email & names), it was all successful!

Output.

```
{ names: 'maotora',
  contract:
   [ File {
       domain: null,
       _events: {},
       _eventsCount: 0,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       size: 11609,
       path: '/tmp/upload_0af5c038e147888f0a7b89ad4784a4dc',
       name: 'Don Joe_08-06-17\'s_contract-for Plot 011.pdf',
       type: 'application/pdf',
       hash: null,
       lastModifiedDate: 2017-09-28T18:56:31.083Z,
       _writeStream: [Object] } ] }
```

I can't use form uploading in the app (just the button to upload without opening a dialog to select file) I only have the filename to the file.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I did, I used [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/) to upload files only.

Comment: I had an alternative solution by converting the data from Node.js `fs.readFile` into a native  JavaScript `File` object. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231241/how-to-create-a-file-object-with-a-path-in-nodejs/76127978#76127978

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been open for a sometime since I couldn't solve the issue with axios and had to use superagent for a while.

However, now that it's [solved](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2) and can use axios just fine, this is how I did solved it on my project.

```js
//- Correctly placing a file_Url into FormData

export function generateContract(url, {names, email}) {
    const file = {
        uri: url,
        name: _.replace(url, /\.[doc,docx,odt,]+$/, ''),
        type: 'docx'
    }

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('contract', file)
    formData.append('names', names)
    formData.append('email', email)

    return formData
}

//- 1. Calling generateContract method
//- 2. Passing the formdata (from method 1) to sendEmail

const contractData = generateContract(contractUrl, payload)
const response = yield sendEmail(contractData)


//- The sendEmail function that makes requests using axios

export function sendEmail(contractData) {
    return checkConnetion()
        .then(() => {
            return axios.post(emailUrl, contractData)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            // return axios.post(emailUrlOffline, contractData)
            userLog('Cannot connect to server, check your internet settings.', 'Connection Error', 'error')
        })
}
```