# How to create a file object in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node project, I am using a file transfer module that only accepts [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects. I only have the absolute path of the file I want to transfer.

I found some questions here on SO going in a similar direction, but they got a workaround by simply implementing the interface of the file object. In my case the library checks the file type by using the check below:

```
function isNativeBlobDefined() {
    return typeof Blob !== 'undefined';
}

function isNativeBlob(p) {
    return isNativeBlobDefined() && p instanceof Blob;
}
```

Is there a possibility to create a file object by just having an absolute path to the file? Something like:

```
const file = File.fromAbsPath(path);
```

In addition to the requirement above, my files can exceed the 8GB mark, which the library can handle (if the file is obtained through the file picker)

Comment: you can using node `fs` module

Comment: I browsed the entire `fs` module, and couldn't find a function that returns the file object I am looking for. Did I miss anything?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231241/how-to-create-a-file-object-with-a-path-in-nodejs

Comment: Thanks! I tried that already. `LocalFileData` doesn't pass the `isNativeBlob` check :-(

Comment: Maybe a module that only works with `File` objects only available on the client-side file may not be the best choice for a server. If you insist on using it maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-file-polyfill will help

Comment: The library is `firebase`, so no alternative insight. `web-file-polyfill` is not suitable unfortunately as I have several files of 1GB in memory. The default File object seems to contain a stream

Comment: @apokryfos `web-file-polyfill` seem to work fantastic with `https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-blob`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I have found to create a file object:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// Create the file
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/file.txt', 'file content');

// Read the file
const fileObject = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/file.txt');
```